# Drupal Node comment redirection when validation fail

Tags: forms, validation, redirect, drupal-7

I've been banging my head on this trying to find a solution, searching all around for something that would work, but I got no chance.

I have a "dashboard" where users have a list of event they took part in where they can rate/comment the event. I'ts basically a custom comment form for a node that is not displaying on the node page itself. The user click on an icon in their dashboard next to the event they want to comment, they get to the form, fill it and it returns them back to the dashboard. The return is adding parameters with a custom submit function and using the redirect function to make sure the user return to the proper tab in their dashboard.

```
function custom_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  if ($form_id == 'comment_node_event_form') {
      $form['#submit'][] = 'customcomment_form_submit';
  }
}

function customcomment_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  if($form['#form_id']=='comment_node_event_form'){
    $pos = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'qt-dashboard');
    
    if ($pos !== FALSE) {
        $form_state['redirect'] = array(
              'dashboard',
              array(
                'query' => array(
                  'qt-dashboard' => '2',
                  'qt-dashboard_event' => '2',
                ),));
    }else{
        $form_state['redirect'] = array(
              'dashboard',
              array(
                'query' => array(
                  'qt-dashboard' => '2',
                  'qt-dashboard_event' => '1',
                  ),));
    }
  }

}
```

This portion is working as it should and expected. The problem is  when form validation fails, it send the comment form error message and form to refill to the node page instead of staying where it is.

I found that if I set the #action with the link where my comment form is, it does send the fail to the proper page

```
$form['#action']='/rating_comment/'.$form['#node']->vid.'?destination=dashboard&qt-dashboard=2&qt-dashboard_event=2';
```

But, doing so break the redirect when successfully submitting the form and it doesn't take the parameter in the redirect..it basically send the user directly to dashboard and **scrapes** the parameter. Now there might be a better solution for form validation fail to stay on the same page and that is pretty much what I am looking for.

Thanks

Comment: use `$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;` into custom submit function

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this form isn’t in your module - and you’re altering the other module. 
Now, when the validate function gets invoked at the end you can check for failure and if there is failure cancel processing/redirect etc.

$form_state['no_redirect'] = FALSE:

Also, you can use the error function to check for errors and if so cancel the rest. This goes inside validate method.

```
  if (form_get_errors()) { return FALSE ; }
  // .. Otherwise, process validation
```

Check out the following

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/170815/is-it-possible-to-stop-a-webform-form-during-submission

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5861/how-to-redirect-to-a-page-after-submitting-a-form

Comment: I will take a look. It's actually the regular node comment form. Thanks, I'll let you know how it turned out.

Comment: Seems like I can't get to work. form_get_errors() does return the errors...using a validate function added to the array it goes in this and I try to do a bunch of things like changing the destination or the action, but it keep submit the form to the node page: comment/reply/NID 
I want the errors to come back to my comment form page...not the node.